# Fuzzy search for fields in adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, security, digital-signature, acrobat

I need help with a document I'm developing. This is a RMA style document with a digital signature. I'm trying to put together a string that will lock the contents of these text field when the document is signed. I have 4 signatures I need to bind to 4 columns with Multiple rows something like 17^19 4 separate times. So the first column's contents all start with 1Q- followed by the item number. I'm trying to fuzzy search "1Q-" and lock any items with that entry in it when the first signature is applied. After That I'm trying to repeat the task for the Second column with each row item in that column starting with 2Q- and correspond that to lock when the second signature is populated.
I know this is super technical but I'm at a loss as a network guy stepping out of my realm into scripting and coding. any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use hierarchical field names, and you can reduce the amount of coding considerably.

Hierarchical field names separate the parts of the full field name with periods, allowing to address groups of fields sharing the same "stem".

So, in your case, you might give your fields a structure like this:

```
Q.cc.rr
```

where cc stands for the column number and rr stands for the row number.

If you have consecutive numbers in cc and rr, you can build loops.